# How to append to a specific line in textfile

Tags: python, function, append, text-files

I have to make a program where someone has to approve or disapprove reviews from a text file and add if it is approved or not. The text file is structured like this:

```
Dave;Good customerservice
Suzan;Bad customerservice
...
```

Now when I use the function all the approvals/disapprovals get appended to the last line, when I instead want it to append to the line that was just judged. What is a simple solution to this? apologies for my bad English.

```py
def function():
    with open("data.txt", "r") as textfile:
        a = textfile.read().splitlines()
        data = [x.split(";") for x in a]
      
        line = 0

    try:
        while True:

            data_to_approve = input(f"{data[line]} ")
            if data_to_approve == "g":
                with open("data.txt", "a") as textfile:
                    textfile.write(";approved")

            elif data_to_approve == "a":
                with open("data.txt", "a") as textfile:
                    textfile.write(";disapproved")

            line += 1

    except IndexError:
        return "You are done."

print(function())
```

Answer (score 0):

`append` method always append's to the end of the file. instead, you can re-write the entire data after modification. it isn't just shorter code, but its way more performant as each opening and closing the storage I/O is very time-consuming compared to ordinary operations.

```py
data = open("data.txt", "r").read().splitlines()

for line in range(len(data)):
    data_to_approve = input(f"{data[line]}")
    if data_to_approve == "g":
        data[line] += ";approved\n"
    else:
        data[line] += ";disaproved\n"

open("data.txt", "w").writelines(data)
```